# Send bitcoins directly from exchange to vendor

Tags: transactions, wallet

I want to buy something at a vendor that accepts btc only.
Can I buy btc from a website like switchere (I'd use SEPA transfer for payment) and send it to the Vendor's wallet directly instead of my own?

Help would be appreciated very much!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to as long as the vendor provides you with a BTC address in a format that the exchange you're using supports.

Also, some exchanges are known to censor transactions to some addresses, so there's a *slight* chance your payment might get denied. That's a risk you take when sending from a custodial exchange... not your keys, not your coins. On the flip side, if the exchange pays the outgoing bitcoin network fee, you'll save that cost.

Hopefully it will work for you.